# Multi-model RDF store vs Graph database

Tags: rdf, graph-databases, owl, multi-model-database, knowledge-graph

I have read the question on SO: [Graph DBs vs. Document DBs vs. Triplestores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043086/graph-dbs-vs-document-dbs-vs-triplestores).

I understand that there's a lot of advantage using OWL/RDFS for semantic data because they are compact and they're just a collection of edges. I was gonna try a triplestore (like Jena) but was wary of certain graph algorithms I couldn't execute on it (like shortest paths and weighed edges).

Ever since I've set out to build something like Google Knowledge Base, I have come across hybrid or multi-model data stores (RDF store + Graph DB), like Blazegraph, Amazon Neptune, Google Cayley (not an actual Google product), Virtuoso, Grakn and the like.

This has gotten me to wonder why I can't just export all the RDF data into a plain and simple Graph Database? Like Neo4j or OrientDB? After all, the RDF data is still a graph. **Why do the creators of Knowledge Graphs insist on using a hybrid store? Why not just use a plain, old graph database?** If you think the answer is optimization, then why not use just a hypergraph database? **What operations on a hybrid database are not available on a graph database?** Let me quote verbatim from a [blog](https://blog.grakn.ai/knowledge-graph-representation-grakn-ai-or-owl-506065bd3f24):

> The emerging paradigm of organising and managing complex, highly interconnected data as so-called knowledge graphs poses a peculiar combination of knowledge and data representation challenges. Knowledge-graph-based applications need to operate efficiently over semantically rich, yet well-structured and constrained graph data. **While relational modelling techniques and graph databases are useful tools to address some of the specific issues, they cannot offer a comprehensive technical and conceptual infrastructure for the entire task.**

In fact, [Sail](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/Sail-Ouplementation) actually provides an RDF layer on top of a graph database (like OrientDB). Doesn't this further reduce the allure of hybrid databases? I do not get the point of building an RDF implementation atop a graph database when RDF data is itself a graph?

Comment: *"why I can't just export all the RDF data into a plain and simple Graph Database?"* - well, you can. Who said that it's not possible? But tell me, which native graph database supports SPARQL, the de facto query language for RDF data? And which graph database supports maybe some rule-based reasoning? And clearly, SPARQL is limited w.r.t. graph operations, like traversal etc. It wasn't never designed for it.

Comment: @UninformedUser, made a good point. Many graph dbs allow importing rdf but the underlying data model is not rdf so you loose many of the nice options relevant for knowledge graph represenation. if you want to build a knowledge graph go for RDF/OWL. If you need a property graph to just link and store documents go for that

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to [tabulated comparison of Database Management Systems](https://linkeddata.uriburner.com/describe/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.openlinksw.com%2Fdata%2Fturtle%2Fgeneral%2Ftabulated-data-comparison.ttl%23content) based on the following:

1. Identifiers
2. Entity Relationship Type (Relations) Modeling
3. Entity Relationship Type (Relations) Structure (N-Tuples, 3-tuples etc.)
4. Entity Relationship Type (Relations) Notations for representing Structure
5. Data Definition and Manipulation Language Support
6. Reasoning and Inference Languages
7. Relevant Open Standards

I can't place the table inline here due to markdown support for table using this particular platform.

[image]